# Error while retrieving data by Id(hashKey) of a dynamoDb table

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch the data from my DynamoDB table based on the Id(HashKey).

**Association.java**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Association")
public class Association {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String adminName;
    private String email;
    private String url;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String password;

    public Association() { }

    public Association(String name, String adminName, String email, String url,
                       String contactNumber, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.adminName = adminName;
        this.email = email;
        this.url = url;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Association(String id, String name, String adminName, String email, String url,
                       String contactNumber, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.adminName = adminName;
        this.email = email;
        this.url = url;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Name")
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="AdminName")
    public String getAdminName() { return adminName; }

    public void setAdminName(String adminName) { this.adminName = adminName; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Email")
    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Url")
    public String getUrl() { return url; }

    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="ContactNumber")
    public String getContactNumber() { return contactNumber; }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) { this.contactNumber = contactNumber; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Password")
    public String getPassword() { return password; }

    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

}
```

**AssociationRepository.java:-**

```
private AmazonDynamoDBClient getDynamoDBClient(){
        AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
        client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(REGION));
        client.setEndpoint(EndPoint);
        return client;
    }

public Association fetchById(String id) {
        DynamoDBConfig dynamoDBConfig = new DynamoDBConfig();
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(getDBClient());
        Association association = new Association();
        association.setId(id);
        Association scanResult = null;
        try {
            scanResult = mapper.load(association);
        }
        catch (Exception exception){
            throw exception;
        }
        return scanResult;
    }
```

Invoking fetchById("123").  Where "123" is an existing Id of the table It throws the below error to me:-

```
{
  "errorMessage": "The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: IT6U9BJ0RAJUDPMLGGR67C542VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)",
  "errorType": "com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1305)",
    "com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:852)",
```

**DYNAMODB TABLE DETAILS:-**

[image]

[image]

I have searched the AWS docs for this but could not find any solution that fixes this.Does anyone of you ever faced this issue?

Comment: Could you provide information about the dynamodb table definition? Table Name, Primary Key, Sort Key (both name and type). As it may be due to a mismatch or a lack of information when querying the table (like sort key defined but not used on query).

Comment: @AlbertoMartin - I have added the details in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you realize, you defined `Name` as your partition key. However on code, you are trying to load an item by the attribute `Id`.

That's not possible as DynamoDB only allows you to load an item by its primary key, which in your case is only the partition key (the attribute `Name`).

So you have to modify either the table to set `Id` as partition key, or create a secondary global index to accomplish that:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: Facing issue while deleting an item - Question is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906671/error-while-deleting-data-from-dynamodb-table .. can u plz help me ?