# Error while deleting data from dynamoDB table

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to delete the data from my DynamoDB table based on the Id(HashKey).

**Association.java**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Association")
public class Association {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String adminName;
    private String email;
    private String url;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String password;

    public Association() { }

    public Association(String name, String adminName, String email, String url,
                       String contactNumber, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.adminName = adminName;
        this.email = email;
        this.url = url;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Association(String id, String name, String adminName, String email, String url,
                       String contactNumber, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.adminName = adminName;
        this.email = email;
        this.url = url;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Name")
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="AdminName")
    public String getAdminName() { return adminName; }

    public void setAdminName(String adminName) { this.adminName = adminName; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Email")
    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Url")
    public String getUrl() { return url; }

    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="ContactNumber")
    public String getContactNumber() { return contactNumber; }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) { this.contactNumber = contactNumber; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Password")
    public String getPassword() { return password; }

    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

}
```

**AssociationRepository.java:-**

```
private AmazonDynamoDBClient getDynamoDBClient(){
        AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
        client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(REGION));
        client.setEndpoint(EndPoint);
        return client;
    }

private void deleteAssociation(String id) {
        try {
            DynamoDBConfig dynamoDBConfig = new DynamoDBConfig();
            DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBConfig.getDBClient());
            Association associationToDelete = new Association();
            associationToDelete.setId(id);
            // Delete the item.
            mapper.delete(associationToDelete);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception);
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

I am getting the below error:-

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: No method annotated with interface com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBRangeKey for class class Association
```

I have searched the AWS docs for this but could not find any solution that fixes this.Does anyone of you ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the same I mentioned on your other post, in DynamoDB you can’t work an item using attributes which are not the primary key (Partition Key only in your scenario).

Moreover, to delete an item it is mandatory to do it by its primary key, so in your case the attribute Name.

Try to do same operation by setting the name, the error is not very descriptive so maybe there is another underlying issue. However, if you don’t meet above requirement it will never work.